# Connecting MYSQL using C program in Eclipse

Tags: mysql, c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am connecting the `Mysql` using `c program in eclipse`, I am using `CYGWIN` compiler to compile program. I have installed the `mysql c connector` and added the include files to the compiler and linker

but i am getting error

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project DbConnectionC ****

make all 
Building file: ../connection.c
Invoking: Cygwin C Compiler
gcc -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -include"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include\mysql.h" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"connection.d" -MT"connection.d" -o "connection.o" "../connection.c"
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: D:\java\workspace\DbConnectionC\Debug
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/d/java/workspace/DbConnectionC/Debug
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
../connection.c: In function `main':
../connection.c:57: warning: char format, different type arg (arg 2)
../connection.c:57: warning: char format, different type arg (arg 2)
../connection.c:61: warning: char format, different type arg (arg 2)
../connection.c:61: warning: char format, different type arg (arg 2)
Finished building: ../connection.c

Building target: DbConnectionC.exe
Invoking: Cygwin C Linker
gcc -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\lib\opt" -o "DbConnectionC.exe"  ./connection.o   -llibmysql.lib -lmysqlclient.lib
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -llibmysql.lib
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient.lib
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [DbConnectionC.exe] Error 1
makefile:29: recipe for target `DbConnectionC.exe' failed

**** Build Finished ****
```

Please help me on this 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the first part you have some warnings about possible problems:

> ../connection.c:39: warning: implicit declaration of function `exit'

This means function `exit()` is not declared, your source needs an `#include <stdlib.h>`

> ../connection.c:46: warning: control reaches end of non-void function

You don't return a value at the end of `main()`, add a `return 0;` if the program succeeds.

In the second part are linker warnings:

> /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -llibmysql.lib
>   /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient.lib

which means the linker needs a path to the libraries or the libraries do not exist or the library names are misspelled.

One possible solution is using `-lmysql -lmysqlclient` instead of `-llibmysql.lib -lmysqlclient.lib`, but I'm not that familiar with Windows.

Having said that, I suggest strongly, you look at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info and look at some book links.

Comment: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -llibmysql.lib
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient.lib          
where should I include these file

Comment: I don't know really, but you can *try* to replace `-llibmysql.lib -lmysqlclient.lib` with `-lmysql -lmysqlclient`